# How to pass values from one function to another in same page of asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have created a list view. Whenever I select an item, I want to pass that value to another event for editing and deleting for selected record.

How can i do that?

**Here's the code:**

```
protected void userList_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e) 
{ 
    userList.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex; 
    uid = userList.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString(); 
    Label1.Text = "Selected username: " + uid; 

    BindGenerics(); 
}
```

Comment: Show us your code?

Comment: What did you try? Are you familiar with ASP.Net?

Comment: You want to pass it to another event or function?

Comment: protected void userList_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e)
    {
        userList.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex;

                uid = userList.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString();
                Label1.Text = "Selected username: " + uid;
                

       
       // edit.Visible = true;
        //delete.Visible = true;

        BindGenerics();
        
         
    }

Comment: take one public variable on selection change of your list view  some this like  i = listview.selecteditem and then use i  for deletin and editng.

Comment: I want that " uid " value to be used in button click event

Comment: please share ur code so we can help you more.

Comment: take on hiidden label and label.text =uid  and use text of uid in button click event u have uid

Answer (score 0):

here are many scenarios
 1st :- do it by java script on selection change on client side append onclick function of buttons edit and delete with value of selected by onselection change  event

2nd :- set value in session and use it further

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
protected void userList_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, ListViewSelectEventArgs e) 
{ 
    userList.SelectedIndex = e.NewSelectedIndex; 
    string uid = userList.DataKeys[e.NewSelectedIndex].Value.ToString(); 
    Label1.Text = "Selected username: " + uid; 

    BindGenerics(); 

    Session["SelectedUserId"] = uid;
}

protectec void edit_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uid = Session["SelectedUserId"].ToString();
    // Do whatever with uid
}

protectec void delete_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string uid = Session["SelectedUserId"].ToString();
    // Do whatever with uid
}
```